# how to use MEF as a Factory

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, mef

I would like to get an instances using MEF abilities.

I have this class which implements an interface :

```
[Export(typeof(IUsersRepository))]
public class UsersRepository : DAL.IUsersRepository
{
```

And I have some service ( this is WCF project ) that uses this `UsersRepository` so this is what I`ve tried to do :

```
    #region Members
    [Import(typeof(IUsersRepository))]
    IUsersRepository UsersRepository;
    #endregion

    #region Constructors 
    public ChatService()
    {
        ICompositionService x = new CompositionContainer(new ApplicationCatalog());
        x.SatisfyImportsOnce(UsersRepository);
    }
    #endregion
```

but, i get two errors(the first is actually a warning) :

1. `UsersRepository` is never used
2. `UsersRepository is null`

Thus i get an exception at:

```
x.SatisfyImportsOnce(UsersRepository);
```

how do i make this in the right way ? ( I did search google and didn't find something helpful for me )

**Edit : ( after reading the first reply )**

So i managed to do the following :

```
   #region Members
    [Import(typeof(IUsersRepository))]
    public IUsersRepository UsersRepository;
    [Import(typeof(IRoomsRepository))]
    public IRoomsRepository RoomsRepository;

    private CompositionContainer _container;
    #endregion

    #region Constructors 
    public ChatService()
    {            
        //An aggregate catalog that combines multiple catalogs
        var catalog = new AggregateCatalog();

        //Adds all the parts found in the same assembly as the Program class
        catalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(ChatService).Assembly));

        //Create the CompositionContainer with the parts in the catalog
        _container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);

        //Fill the imports of this object
        try
        {
            this._container.ComposeParts(this);
        }
        catch (CompositionException compositionException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(compositionException.ToString());
        }
    }
    #endregion
```

but yet i get the following error :

> No exports were found that match the constraint : ContractName
>   DAL.IUsersRepository  RequiredTypeIdentity DAL.IUsersRepository

Though i did define the export class for this interface as said above .

Comment: `UsersRepository` is probably defined in another assembly - create a `DirectoryCatalog` instead of an `AssemblyCatalog`

Comment: I solved it with : catalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.Load("DAL")));

Answer (score 1):

Why not doing it the regular way?

```
[ImportMany]
private IEnumerable<Lazy<IPostHandler, IPostHandlerCapabilities>> _postHandlersPlugins = null;
private CompositionContainer _compositionContainer;

......
public void SomeInitFunction() 
{
    catalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(assembly));
    _compositionContainer = new CompositionContainer(catalog);

    try
    {
        _compositionContainer.ComposeParts(this);
    }
    catch (CompositionException ex)
    {
        ;
    }
}
```

the _postHandlersPlugins are the entities which are decorated with the Export attribute, please note regarding the state - as you can work in shared state (singelton - by default) or for every request of the item it will be recreated, I am working with lazy so the plugins will be created when some one really needs it. regarding the init - most of the time it is called from the ctor. the container is the place holder where to search all the parts (classes with the export attribute)

[LINK TO MSDN - MEF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

when you are debugging it watch the catalog and see if it find parts. if it find your parts and they they arent created after the composition - it can be that you dont have default CTOR and it failed to compose cause it can resolve the params. and if you dont see the part in the catalog - it means that you have added the wrong assembly to the catalog

Comment: Im pretty new with this, can you add some more explanation? where do you use _postHandlersPlugins ? where do i tell the container to create an instance of my required class ?